# Descargar imagen con C# y Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Estoy creando un botón con Javascript el cual va a estar dentro de un form, y cuando se haga clic sobre él, va a mandar su value al método del controlador que le estoy indicando, y asi poder descargar una imagen.

Asi es como estoy haciendo al método de C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult DescargarImagenIndividual(string imagenSelec)
{
    string consulta, ruta = "";
    string[] splitImg;
 
    try
    {
        splitImg = imagenSelec.Split("/");
        
        using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";" + ";username=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";"))
        {
            consulta = "SELECT e.Path FROM Entrega e WHERE e.Entrega LIKE '%@entrega%'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrega", splitImg[4]);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ruta = reader["Path"].ToString();
            }

        }
        string contentType = "image/png";
        byte[] bites = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
            $"attachment; filename=\"{ruta}\"");
        return File(bites, contentType);
    }
}
```

Y así es cómo creo el botón desde Javascript:

```
let btnDescargar = document.createElement('btn');
btnDescargar.setAttribute("type", "submit");
btnDescargar.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
btnDescargar.setAttribute('value', img.src);
btnDescargar.textContent = "Descargar Imágen";
btnDescargar.setAttribute('name', 'imagenSelec');

let form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('action', '~/Home/DescargarImagenIndividual');

form.appendChild(btnDescargar);
```

El botón se me crea correctamente pero no está descargando nada. No estoy muy seguro de que esté creado correctamente, no tengo mucho conocimiento del lenguaje.

¿Por qué me complico la vida haciendo todo ésto si tengo una opcion llamada "download" en html? Poque las imágenes que estoy mostrando son de una carpeta temporal, y yo necesito descargar las imágenes temporales que están en otra.

Parece que la funcion de javascript está funcionando bien, ya que cree un `Logger` para ver el erro y me dice:

> Empty path name is not legal. (Parameter 'path')

***ACTUALIZACIÓN***

El error previamente posteado a sido arreglado, ahora estoy teniendo otro error...

Supongamos que las ultimas lineas de código es:

```
string contentType = "image/png";
byte[] bites = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
$"attachment; filename=\"{ruta}\"");
return File(bites, contentType);
```

(Igual al primer posteo)

Bueno, esto me descarga la imagen pero con la ruta del directorio, por lo que no lo veo correcto. Es decir `wwwroot/imagenes/[nombre de imagen].jpg`

Aprovechando que `File()` tiene como tercer parámetro "`string fileDownloadName`",  le pongo un nombre por ejemplo "Imagen Descargada". Pero ésto evita que pueda descargar el archivo `.jpg`, y en su lugar me descarga un archivo de extencion `ARCHIVO`

```
string contentType = "image/png";
byte[] bites = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ruta);
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
$"attachment; filename=\"{ruta}\"");
return File(bites, contentType, "Imagen Entrega");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, el archivo de arriba es con el segundo código, y el `.jpg` del primer código...

Comment: Saludos Mr. Popo, ¿en qué línea salta ese error?

Comment: Hola @fredyfx ! vi que solamente era un error de señalización, se arregló declarando la variable `ruta` y asignándole un valor inicial. Ahora estoy teniendo otro problema, ayer pude resolver el boton y se descargaba la imagen correctamente, pero hoy me descarga archivos de tipo "`archivo`" y no `JPG` o como corresponde

Comment: Agregas un header con filename=\"{ruta}\" ahí debe ir el nombre del archivo